# Packing JRE into an Exe File Jar2Exe

Tags: java

I'm trying to send a copy of a GUI game I made to my friends, but they are getting the error: No Java Runtime Environment Found.

I'm using Jar2Exe to turn the jar into an exe.

I found this solution online, but I don't know where to start.

"If you want your software can run on a pc without JRE "installed", you can select to copy a 'jre' along with your program and pack them into install file together."

How can I bundle a jre with it? I don't want this to be an install file, I just want it to run off an exe.

Answer (score 0):

im a little confused here, i think all computers must have installed JRE, because java is used with so many aplications, for example if you could achieve to bubdle JRE inside your game ( jar file ), what happens if your JRE is for windows, and your friend want to play in MAC OS X, or GNU/LINUX?

if you made you game should work in each OS, obvioulsy the require JRE for their respective OS, but if you are getting an error then os not problem of JRE, but your game...

Comment: Well the game works for me? After sending the exe to someone though it doesn't work for them.

Comment: well, then ask then if they have the same version of JRE installed in their PC's, or if they have the same version of java you used to make the game, for example if you made the game in java 8 and they have JRE 7, it wont work

Comment: the game was exported out of eclipse with Jre 1.8.0_102. He doesn't have Jre 1.8.0_102, he has Jre 1.8.0_51. Does version of java 8 matter? What else could be the problem?